# Javascript function clicking one button and obtaining different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, input

```
<input type="button" name="name" value="Enero" id="mytext" onclick="my()">


function my() {

    var poop = document.getElementById("mytext").value

    if (poop = "Enero") {
        poop = "Febrero"

    } else if (poop = "Febrero") {
        poop = "Marzo"

    } else if (poop = "Marzo") {
        poop = "Abril"
    }
}
```

Hey I'm trying to make a function  in an input button so that when you press click , the value of the button changes to different values depending of the clicks you give.

For example the default value is "Enero" (January in Spanish), so you click on in and its changes to "Febrero" consecutively until it returns to "Enero" and the cycle starts again.

(You can help me with a Jquery function or a Javascript function)

Comment: Use `=` for assignements and `==` or `===` for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix the months spelling (idk Spanish so I guessed) and add the rest of them to the array..

```js
function my() {
  var poop = document.getElementById('poop');
  var mnths = ['janurenao', 'februareano', 'marcheano', 'aprileona', 'may-eona'];
  var index = mnths.indexOf(poop.value);
  if (index > -1) {
    index++;
    if(index === mnths.length) index = 0;
    poop.value = mnths[index];
  }
}
```

```html
<input value='janurenao' id='poop' />
<button onclick='my()'>pressme</button>
```

Comment: Good solution, but you need to check for the last item in the array.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce., Thanks a lot , that function rocks ! , and nice spanish try haha I laughed a lot haha

Answer (score 2):

In javascript a single equals is an assignment, so you want to change all your `if` statements to `==`or `===` instead like:

```
function my() {

var poop = document.getElementById("mytext").value

    if (poop === "Enero") {
        poop = "Febrero"

    } else if (poop === "Febrero") {
        poop = "Marzo"

    } else if (poop === "Marzo") {
        poop = "Abril"
    }
}
```